# Delphi version 2007 reading Cyrillic email with TIdMessage

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

We have built an email service that reads emails (from IMAP) and put them into a table in a database. And it works for German / English text, but now I want to get all other emails, like Cyrillic or Chinese too. But the characters that I receive are something like this: ĐżĐľĐ˝ĐľĐ˛Đľ Ń‚ĐµŃŃ‚Đ¸Ń€Đ°ĐĽ or even just ?????.

We are using ADO objects to store data in database and column type for those fields are declared as nvarchar, also parameters of a stored procedure that is used to upload that data are nvarchar too.

I presume that is the problem with Delphi 2007, but still I read on some posts here and there that Delphi 2007 supports Unicode (if Unicode I need). So, does anybody knows how to read email with Cyrillic and store it in mssql table?

To get text from IdMessage I am using IdMessage.Body.Text

Thanks,
Dejan

And INDY version is 10.1.5

Comment: Did you set `IdMessage.Charset := 'Windows-1251'` ?

Comment: Charset is UTF-8

Comment: You are using a seriously outdated version of Indy and need to upgrade. The current version is 10.6.2. Modern versions have much better Unicode handling. In any case, D2007 is NOT a Unicode version (you need D2009+ for that) so all strings are ANSI, which can't handle languages like Chinese that really require Unicode

Comment: Thanks Remy, but I am working on a app that is big and already built on that version of Indy, we already tried to upgrade it, but we just got ourselves in big mess afterwards

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to make it working by using UTF8Decode function.

I have tested it with UTF-8 and ANSI charsets and it works in both cases (of course ANSI will produce ? in the places of Unicode characters).

declare BodyText and subject as WideStrings

after that just use:

```
BodyText := UTF8Decode(IdMessage.Body.GetText)
```

Comment: If you have an additional question to ask, that would be a new question. Don't ask a new question in an answer.